# Executing googleapi Curl (curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL)

Tags: format

To get an access-token i have to execute this curl command:
curl -L -X POST 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&code=4/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=https://www.google.com'

but i get this error:
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
The "client_secret" command is either misspelled or
could not be found.
The "code" command is either misspelled or
could not be found.
The "grant_type" command is either misspelled or
could not be found.
The "redirect_uri" command is either misspelled or
could not be found.

I'm using Windows 10 console. Any ideas how to fix this? I also tried to execute this in powershell.

Also tried it with powershell.